# Cannot set up OAuthentication

Tags: sharepoint, oauth, cloud, sharepoint-online

We are trying to connect an internal application to Sharepoint 365. The goal is to read data from Sharepoint 365 lists and Excel documents. We want to take advantage of the fact we already use OAuthentication and basically our users login with their own Windows credentials. Now, to accomplish that we first need to register an application with Sharepoint which we did using this link:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx

After that we also need to get an authorization code for clients to login with their Windows account. We do that with this URL:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/_layouts/15/OAuthAuthorize.aspx?client_id=14f0e39c-1234-42ea-bed5-ee5c7c834655&scope=List.Read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.mycompany.com%3A9090%2Foauth%2F2.0%2FredirectURL.jsp

When we run that last link we get the error below:

```
Sorry, something went wrong
There is no claims identity. Please make sure the web application is configured to use Claims Authentication.
TECHNICAL DETAILS

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
Correlation ID: 367ee69f-5066-0000-e1ef-cee55f7b7000
```

As you can see, the error is not very helpful. I have done already lots of research and answers vary from lack of higher level of access, to invalid URL request. I have elevated access and the URL is well constructed. Yet the error persist.

So, my question, what is the meaning of the error? Why is not executing?

Comment: Experiencing this as well across multiple applications, and across multiple tenants.  The ACS client ID/secrets are not listed as expired in the Seller Dashboard.  Really perplexing.

Comment: We have logged a Microsoft case #21709730.  The problem has also been [reported here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/522147/oauthentication-with-office-365-failure-there-is-n.html).

Comment: Thank you! I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We logged a Microsoft Premier Support ticket and behold! the problem has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help!